# I have used map in Android app its working on my phone and emulator but its apk not working on other phones

Tags: android, dictionary

I have used map in Android app its working on my phone and emulator but its apk not working on other phones .SHA1 fingerprint is already generated. I have tried API key in both debug/res/values/ and release/res/values.Please tell me what I am missing. I'll highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you be more specific in regard to why it's not working?

Comment: Maybe I am forgetting things (it was long ago when I used it), but I think there is one **.SHA1 fingerprint** for testing purposes and another to use on the release apk version of your app. I would check it.

Comment: Map is loading when I'm compiling on my android phone or emulator but when I run the app-debug.apk file on any other phone, map doesn't load.